# Prism Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page Navigation not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, tabbedpage

when I want to navigate to the tabbed page the application stopped but when I create a new project and add the tabbed page working fine any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same behaviour after upgrading to Prism 8

To reproduce this behaviour I added a demo app to [github](https://github.com/uwe-e/PrismPages)
By default, the App uses Prism 7.2. This works fine.

After upgrading Prism to version 8, ...
[image]

I was unable to navigate between pages within a tab.

After downgrading Prism to an earlier version everything works fine again.